# Strategy for animating a large mesh in three.js?

Tags: three.js, jquery-animate, shader, mesh

I am relatively new to three.js but not OpenGL (though it has been a while :-).  I am working my way though a bunch of examples to familiarize myself with three.js.  I decided to port some of the NeHe demos.  Most are easy enough (though educational).  Demo 11, however, is essentially creating a large (45x45) mesh of GL_Quads (in the old OpenGL) and mapping a texture to each set of vertices.  Then on each animation frame, then mesh's Z values are changed and the mesh re-created to cause it to ripple.

In OpenGL 1.x with C++ or Java, no big deal.  It works well to simply recreate the vertices and the texture mapping.  In three.js it was easy enough to code (changing each set of vertices to a pair of triangular faces, but the performance is abysmal.

I saw the demo of the waving cloth on the three.js site (http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html) which looks like it uses the shaders directly t o do the work.  So my question is, am I missing something (like there is an efficient way to do this without descending to the shader level) or is time for me to learn more about shaders?

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic vertex update in js I threw together for you...

It runs pretty good on my machine... Is this similar to what you tried to implement?

Building terrain entirely on the GPU is feasible but pretty complicated, and for most cases involving terrain, you still need to have the actual mesh on the CPU side to interact with it/perform collision, etc. so you'll end up implementing both a GPU and CPU version.

Another approach is to generate the geometry on the CPU like in this example, but then use a custom shader to perform just texturing and lighting based on the information in the mesh.

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var w = 300;
var h = 200;
renderer.setSize(w, h);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  45, // Field of view
  w / h, // Aspect ratio
  0.1, // Near
  10000 // Far
);
camera.position.set(15, 10, 15);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0x808080);
light.position.set(20, 20, 20);
scene.add(light);
var light1 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x808080);
light1.position.set(20, 20, 20);
scene.add(light1);
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0x800000);
light2.position.set(-20, 20, -20);
scene.add(light2);
var light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0x0000FF);
light3.position.set(-20, -20, -20);
scene.add(light3);


var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x808080
});
var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 45, 45);

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, material);
scene.add(mesh);
renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd, 1);


(function animate() {
  var t0 = performance.now() * 0.01;
  var t1 = t0 * 0.7;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  controls.update();

  var sinm = (v, m) => {
    return Math.sin(v) * m
  }
  var noisefn = (x, y) => {
    return sinm((x * 0.2) + (y * 0.7) + t0, 1) + sinm((x * 0.9) + (y * 1.2) + t1, 0.3) + sinm((x * -0.9) + (y * 2.2) + t1, 0.4)
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < planeGeom.vertices.length; i++) {
    var v = planeGeom.vertices[i];
    v.z = noisefn(v.x, v.y);
  }
  planeGeom.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  planeGeom.computeFaceNormals();
  planeGeom.computeVertexNormals();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this case is that I can solve my problem with the ParametricGeometry since the shape and its variance is very simple.  A more complex surface (like a real 3D terrain) probably will require learning about shaders.  Sounds like fun, but think I'll walk before running.

UPDATE:  Using a ParametricGeometry works, and is faster but the performance is still poor.  So I'll look at other solutions, such as descending to the shader level.

Comment: With a bit more work I created this http://www.geofx.com/graphics/nehe-three-js/lessons09-16/lesson11/lesson11.html.  Works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use a shader for that.

If it doesn't need to be all dynamic from code but you could use pre-made data, using morph targets and the already existing shader for displaying those would work fine I think.

But for a fully dynamic thing like a water where you can throw stones I think you need your own  (similar) shader. Hopefully is easy enough with the examples etc., do share when get it done if you can :)